# Error : React.createClass is not a function [WebDataRocks]

Tags: webdatagrid, webdatarocks

I'm trying to use WebDataRocks(npm) with React(v16.14.0) and its failing with the below error "React.createClass is not a function"

Does it support React(v16.14.0)?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there was an issue with React v16.14.0.

[The PropTypes have been moved from React to their own package `prop-types`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), so they need to be imported separately.

The [webdatarocks.react.js](https://github.com/WebDataRocks/pivot-react/blob/master/ES6/src/webdatarocks.react.js) file got updated and now it works well with React v16.14.0. Here is a link to a [WebDataRocks sample React project on GitHub](https://github.com/WebDataRocks/pivot-react/tree/master/ES6) for reference.